# Virtual Directory in Web Config

Tags: web-config, virtual-directory

I am trying to add a virtual directory to my web config file so I can share master pages and images accross different applications.  I have found very limited information and would apperciate any ideas you may have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can add virtual directores in the web.config - has to be done in IIS.

Comment: Can this be done inside Visual Studio then?  It has its own IIS Server correct?

Comment: Visual Studio's web server can't do virtual directories. You could use the IIS on your machine instead. Go to project properties -> web and select "use local IIS server".